# Erro: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value[...]

Tags: jsf, primefaces, cookies

Como solucionar esse erro do HIbernate? Pois o mesmo é indicado como

> Grave: JSF1094: Could not decode flash data from incoming cookie value Invalid characters in decrypted value.  Processing will continue, but the flash is unavailable for this request.

Esse aviso aparece quando abro algumas páginas.

O JSF fica imprimindo a cada segundo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou usando o `Primefaces 6.2` e `hibernate 4.3.11.Final`.